# SQL How To Apply Calculation on Only Numeric Values Using Case Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data that is stored as either numeric or varchar values.

I am doing the following so that if the value is numeric I just wanted to display whatever it is.  If the value is numeric I want to apply a calculation on it.  How can I accomplish this?

Currently, I get the error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Here is my select statement:

```
select 
    case 
       when IsNumeric(value) = 1
          then cast(value as decimal(6, 2)) / coalesce(divider)
       else value 
    end as [value]
```

Comment: FYI its a case *expression* not a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a column result with a `numeric` as result and a `varchar` result in same time, try this:

```
select case when IsNumeric(value) = 1
            then cast(value as decimal(6,2))/nullif(divider, 0)
            else null end as [value]
```

or cast result to divide to `varchar`:

```
select divider, 
case 
when divider=0 then value
when IsNumeric(value) = 1 then cast( cast(value as Decimal(6,2))/divider as varchar(2000)) 
else value end as [value]
```

Note: you should check divider is never equal to 0 in your case.

Comment: This works to not generate an error and apply the calculation when the field is numeric.  However, I do not get the value of the field if it is nonnumeric and I need that value too.  I'm open to redesigning the query to be able to accomplish this. Perhaps I need multiple stes?

Comment: same you my second proposition?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that, but yes! That resolves my issue. And yes, I actually have a `/coalesce(divider)` in my code so I don't get divide by 0 error. Thanks!

Comment: coalesce with only one argument work, i'm surprise by this

Comment: and coalesce is for null not for zero

Comment: I have modified my querys for take case diviver = 0

Answer (score 5):

`ISNUMERIC` is notoriously bad at being accurate about a value being actually numeric .....

It would be much simpler to use `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT` - these functions will return `NULL`, if a value cannot be converted as desired:

```
SELECT
    TRY_CAST(value AS DECIMAL(6, 2)) / COALESCE(NULLIF(divider, 0))
```

Get more details [at the official MS docs site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql)

Furthermore, the `CASE` **expression** in T-SQL must return the **same datatype** for all possible returns - returning a `DECIMAL` in one case, and an `NVARCHAR` in another will not work anyway....

Comment: `NULLIF(divider, 0)` - just in case

Comment: i dont knew TRY_CAST, ty